# Why won't my Javascript function be called with the onLoad event?

Tags: javascript, function, call

I was trying to test my code...but I can't get any Javascript function to be called. I've tried a lot of things: Making buttons to call my existing function, trying to call new functions in with this code, inserting my function into previously successful HTML files. None of these strategies have worked. Whatever I do, any Javascript function in this file will not be called, or appears to not be called. I have no idea why.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Template Page</title>
</head>

<body onLoad="chooser()">

<!--HTML "route" for images-->
<img src="IMG_0000.jpg"></img>
<img src="IMG_0001.jpg"></img>
<img src="IMG_0002.jpg"></img>
<img src="IMG_0003.jpg"></img>
<img src="IMG_0004.jpg"></img>

<script type="text/javascript">

//Create a list of images, choose randomly for that list (to display on the page), and then delete that image from the list
function chooser()
{
    //Declare variables
    var start = 0;
    var end = 9;
    var images = [];
    var imageNumber = start;
    var imageName = "";

    //Add image src's to array
    while (imageNumber <= end)
    {
        if (imageNumber < 10)
        {
            imageName = "IMG_000" + string(imageNumber) + ".jpg";
        }

        else if (imageNumber > 9) && (imageNumber < 100)
        {
            imageName = "IMG_00" + string(imageNumber) + ".jpg";
        }

        else if (imageNumber > 99) && (imageNumber < 1000)
        {
            imageName = "IMG_0" + string(imageNumber) + ".jpg";
        }

        else if (imageNumber > 999) && (imageNumber < 10000)
        {
            imageName = "IMG_" + string(imageNumber) + ".jpg";
        }

        images.push(imageName);
        imageNumber = imageNumber + 1;
        alert(images);
    }
}

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I should also add that I've checked for syntax errors multiple times and used many lint checkers. I may have missed something though.

Comment: have you considered opening javascript console? I've got a lot of syntax error with your code...

Comment: Why must it be called in the onLoad? just call it after it's defined. Or better yet, ditch the function and put the script in the HEAD.

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error in your `else-if` parts, here's the correct one:

```
    if (imageNumber < 10)
    {
        imageName = "IMG_000" + string(imageNumber) + ".jpg";
    }

    else if ((imageNumber > 9) && (imageNumber < 100))
    {
        imageName = "IMG_00" + string(imageNumber) + ".jpg";
    }

    else if ((imageNumber > 99) && (imageNumber < 1000))
    {
        imageName = "IMG_0" + string(imageNumber) + ".jpg";
    }

    else if ((imageNumber > 999) && (imageNumber < 10000))
    {
        imageName = "IMG_" + string(imageNumber) + ".jpg";
    }
```

and also that function-like `string()`, what do you want with them? Convert imageNumber from integer to string? In that case, you don't need anything. "+" operator will automatically convert the numbers to string. So remove those `string()` making your final code to:

```
    if (imageNumber < 10)
    {
        imageName = "IMG_000" + imageNumber + ".jpg";
    }

    else if ((imageNumber > 9) && (imageNumber < 100))
    {
        imageName = "IMG_00" + imageNumber + ".jpg";
    }

    else if ((imageNumber > 99) && (imageNumber < 1000))
    {
        imageName = "IMG_0" + imageNumber + ".jpg";
    }

    else if ((imageNumber > 999) && (imageNumber < 10000))
    {
        imageName = "IMG_" + imageNumber + ".jpg";
    }
```

Comment: ZOMG. I knew it would be something that simple. Thank you very much.